# Simplification of large function IF in Pine Script v4

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to write a script that will help automatically change the input of "MASignalPeriod" depending on which cryptocurrency is viewed during the operation of the indicator. I also want to be able to make changes manually, through the menu, so I made the dependence on the checkbox "Settingmode". Everything works, but the indicator started to run for a very long time. For it to work, I need 4 such pieces of code for every 20 cryptocurrencies (random ones are selected in the code), which means that it will take even longer to load.

My code is as follows -

```
//------------- MASignalPeriod input -------------//
MASignalPeriod = if Settingmode == false and syminfo.ticker == "DYDXUSDTPERP" // 1
    MASignalPeriod = 15
else
    if Settingmode == false and syminfo.ticker == "GALAUSDTPERP" // 2
        MASignalPeriod = 15
    else
        if Settingmode == false and syminfo.ticker == "DOTUSDTPERP" // 3
            MASignalPeriod = 15
        else
            if Settingmode == false and syminfo.ticker == "ATOMUSDTPERP" // 4
                MASignalPeriod = 15
            else
                if Settingmode == false and syminfo.ticker == "GALAUSDTPERP" // 5
                    MASignalPeriod = 15
                else
                    if Settingmode == false and syminfo.ticker == "DOTUSDTPERP" // 6
                        MASignalPeriod = 15
                    else
                        if Settingmode == false and syminfo.ticker == "ATOMUSDTPERP" // 7
                            MASignalPeriod = 15
                        else
                            if Settingmode == false and syminfo.ticker == "GALAUSDTPERP" // 8
                                MASignalPeriod = 15
                            else
                                if Settingmode == false and syminfo.ticker == "DOTUSDTPERP" // 9
                                    MASignalPeriod = 15
                                else
                                    if Settingmode == false and syminfo.ticker == "ATOMUSDTPERP" // 10
                                        MASignalPeriod = 15
                                    else
                                        if Settingmode == false and syminfo.ticker == "GALAUSDTPERP" // 11
                                            MASignalPeriod = 15
                                        else
                                            if Settingmode == false and syminfo.ticker == "DOTUSDTPERP" // 12
                                                MASignalPeriod = 15
                                            else
                                                if Settingmode == false and syminfo.ticker == "ATOMUSDTPERP" // 13
                                                    MASignalPeriod = 15
                                                else
                                                    if Settingmode == false and syminfo.ticker == "GALAUSDTPERP" // 14
                                                        MASignalPeriod = 15
                                                    else
                                                        if Settingmode == false and syminfo.ticker == "DOTUSDTPERP" // 15
                                                            MASignalPeriod = 15
                                                        else
                                                            if Settingmode == false and syminfo.ticker == "ATOMUSDTPERP" // 16
                                                                MASignalPeriod = 15
                                                            else
                                                                if Settingmode == false and syminfo.ticker == "GALAUSDTPERP" // 17
                                                                    MASignalPeriod = 15
                                                                else
                                                                    if Settingmode == false and syminfo.ticker == "DOTUSDTPERP" // 18
                                                                        MASignalPeriod = 15
                                                                    else
                                                                        if Settingmode == false and syminfo.ticker == "DOTUSDTPERP" // 19
                                                                            MASignalPeriod = 15
                                                                        else
                                                                            if Settingmode == false and syminfo.ticker == "DOTUSDTPERP" // 20
                                                                                MASignalPeriod = 15
                                                                            else
                                                                                MASignalPeriod = input(15, title="MA Signal Period", group="Signals settings")
```

Please help me to simplify this feature.

Thanks & regards.

Comment: Why do you have all tose checks if at the end all will have `MASignalPeriod = 15` ?

Comment: I think this is just a proof of concept. Those `= 15` could be changed according to the desired outcome per entry.

Comment: Yes, the number 15 is introduced as an example, for each cryptocurrency will be selected its value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed a bug in the code, maybe this feature will come in handy.
This script allows you to save in the code unique settings for the input data of the indicator for each coin. SMA as an example of an indicator, it can be seen on any indicator you need. The numbers 100/200/300 go as variables for each coin. If the coin is different, the default settings are active 15.

```
MASignalPeriod = input(15, title="MA Signal Period", group="Signals settings")
if not Settingmode
    MASignalPeriod := 
     syminfo.ticker == "DYDXUSDTPERP" ? 100 : 
     syminfo.ticker == "GALAUSDTPERP" ? 200 : 
     syminfo.ticker == "DOTUSDTPERP" ? 300 : 
     MASignalPeriod
SMA = sma(open,MASignalPeriod)
plot(SMA)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can extract `Settingmode` to simplify the structure:

```
MASignalPeriod = 0
if not Settingmode
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "DYDXUSDTPERP" ? 15 : MASignalPeriod
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "GALAUSDTPERP" ? 15 : MASignalPeriod
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "DOTUSDTPERP" ? 15 : MASignalPeriod
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "ATOMUSDTPERP" ? 15 : MASignalPeriod
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "GALAUSDTPERP" ? 15 : MASignalPeriod
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "DOTUSDTPERP" ? 15 : MASignalPeriod
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "ATOMUSDTPERP" ? 15 : MASignalPeriod
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "GALAUSDTPERP" ? 15 : MASignalPeriod
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "DOTUSDTPERP" ? 15 : MASignalPeriod
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "ATOMUSDTPERP" ? 15 : MASignalPeriod
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "GALAUSDTPERP" ? 15 : MASignalPeriod
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "DOTUSDTPERP" ? 15 : MASignalPeriod
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "ATOMUSDTPERP" ? 15 : MASignalPeriod
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "GALAUSDTPERP" ? 15 : MASignalPeriod
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "DOTUSDTPERP" ? 15 : MASignalPeriod
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "ATOMUSDTPERP" ? 15 : MASignalPeriod
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "GALAUSDTPERP" ? 15 : MASignalPeriod
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "DOTUSDTPERP" ? 15 : MASignalPeriod
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "DOTUSDTPERP" ? 15 : MASignalPeriod
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "DOTUSDTPERP" ? 15 : MASignalPeriod
```

This almost looks like switch-case which Pine 5 have introduced, you might have a look at that: https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/say-hello-to-pine-script-v5-26900/

Comment: Karatedog thanks for the feedback and your help.

Tried this code. The script is compiled, but shows the error "Invalid value of the length argument (0.0) in the 'rma' function. It must be> 0." If the value "Settingmode" = "false". If you set the checkbox to "true" it starts.
(hereinafter referred to as "MASignalPeriod" is used to calculate "rma")

I also tried to use version 5, but I do not understand how to add the variable "Settingmode" as a trigger in the "switch" function. This would actually optimize the code

Comment: Doesn't this always set `MASignalPeriod` to 0 unless `syminfo.ticker=="DOTUSDTPERP"`?

Comment: No, the goal was to choose the value before ":"

Comment: Fixed the code to tolerate for fall-through.

Answer (score 0):

I slightly adapted the recommended code from @karatedog and got the result, but it works with a bug - if you select the value "false" in Settingmode, then the selected value for the coin is taken into account only on the last coin, on the previous coins the default value is taken, not the selected one. For example in DYDXUSDTPERP we receive value 15, and it is necessary to receive 100. Though if to choose DOTUSDTPERP we receive desirable value 300:

```
MASignalPeriod = input(15, title="MA Signal Period", group="Signals settings")
if not Settingmode
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "DYDXUSDTPERP" ? 100 : 0
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "GALAUSDTPERP" ? 200 : 0
    MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "DOTUSDTPERP" ? 300 : 15
SMA = sma(open,MASignalPeriod)
plot(SMA)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, stupid me. Whenever the conditionals check for a certain symbol and the result is `false` it will put 0 to the `MASignalPeriod` variable which might have the good value in it from a previous conditional. This needs to be modified to tolerate "fall-through": `MASignalPeriod := syminfo.ticker == "DYDXUSDTPERP" ? 100 : MASignalPeriod`

Comment: Thanks, man. I will change a little more so that the code was not one row